# Converting dataframe columns to dummies if under x unique value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to make a function which converts columns in pandas dataframe to dummies if the column contains less than a certain amount of unique value. My function looks like this in the current state:

```
for i in range(columns):
    unique_values = df1[[i]].apply(pd.Series.nunique) # then we find unique values within column i

    unique_values1 = unique_values.iloc[0] # then we select unique values within column i

    if unique_values1 < 5: # if unique values is below 8 then we dummy that variable 

        dummys = pd.get_dummies(df1.ix[:, i]) # we make specific dummy for column i

        df2 = pd.concat([df2, dummys], axis=1) # we merge dummy's onto original dataframe

else:

    pass
```

However, I think there may be a cleaner solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all that in a one-liner actually.

Here's some dummy data:

```
      a     b     c
0  Var2  Var1  Var3
1  Var1  Var2  Var2
2  Var1  Var2  Var1
3  Var1  Var3  Var1
4  Var1  Var2  Var1
```

Let's load it and see:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# If nunique is < 3, then we encode. Here only column 'a' should be encoded
cutoff = 3

pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns[df.apply(pd.Series.nunique) < cutoff], drop_first=True)
```

Here's the result:

```
      b     c  a_Var2
0  Var1  Var3       1
1  Var2  Var2       0
2  Var2  Var1       0
3  Var3  Var1       0
4  Var2  Var1       0
```